# JS for buttons, Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, html

I was browsing for examples for my page and ran across a weird JQuery selector. Can any of you explain how does it work, and can I use it to select ID's in HTML which have unique indexing.

```
//The selector which I don't know how it works
//what is "^" exactly for?
"div[id^='myModal']"



//How Jquery for me dyanimcally creates HTML with Array elements and indexes ID's
 id=\"Modals_" +index+ "\"
```

Answer (score 1):

a[href^="https"]    this mean is Selects every  element whose href attribute value begins with "https"
 you can find meaning of selector in this link 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

about `id=\"Modals_" +index+ "\"`index is variable and you can use this for ID like this code

```
ID="Modals_"+index
$("p").attr("id",ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

"div[id^='myModal']" it means that all the div's with starting of ID element with "myModal" for exmple myModal1, myModal2 etc/...............